# How do I delete rows in a dataframe based on numpy where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a code where I use numpy to transform a dataframe to an array to calculate the hamming distance between the different entries in the array.

To find the unwanted entries i use a np.where-statement which returns the following:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=int32)
```

There four numbers are equal to the row-index in the dataframe. My question is how I can transform this array to someting so I can tell dataframe to drop these?

EDIT:
This is how the code looks like right now with example data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['csk_1', 'csk_2', 'csk_3', 'csk_4', 'csk_5', 'csk_6', 'csk_7', 'csk_8', 'csk_9', 'csk_10', 'csk_11', 'csk_12', 'csk_13'])

enc = OrdinalEncoder()
X = enc.fit_transform(df.to_numpy())
j = 0
totals = (len(X) - 1)
threshold = 1

while j < totals:
    idx = len(X) - j - 1
    row = X[idx]
    prev_rows = X[0:idx]
    dists = np.sum(row != prev_rows, axis=1)
    a = np.where(dists <= threshold)
    df = df.drop(a.flatten(), axis=0)
    X = enc.fit_transform(df.to_numpy())
    j = j + 1
print(df)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, from [the pandas drop() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html): "labels  (list-like):
Index or column labels to drop" If you have the indices you want to drop, have you tried using them in the drop method?

Comment: Yes I've tried ths but not succeeded. I'm quite new to Python so I think it's my lack of knowledge which makes me fail.

Comment: See this link on how to create a [mcve], which will help us to know how to help you better in the future. Sample input, expected output, and code for what you've tried so far (with the full traceback of any error) gives us an idea of where you're stuck

Comment: Single argument, `np.where`, or rather `np.nonzero` can give you the indices that could be used in a `drop` function.  The usual 3 argument `where` used in `pandas` is not useful; it generates values based on conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to convert the array to list and then use `df.drop`

```
a = array([1,2,3,4])
a = a.tolist()
df = df.drop(df.index[[a]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried this before but I get following error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: `drop()` can take an array just as easily as a list, it just needs to be flattened into a 1D array

Comment: show a sample of data or the where function to see what type is generated, or let me know if Anderson idea worked out

Comment: I've added example code with a data sample as well

Comment: So this is working, but will fail after two iterations as the index will be out of range:

`a = np.array(a).tolist()
    print(a)
    df = df.drop(df.index[a])`

Comment: don't forget to reset your index after each iteration
`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is likely tripping you up is that you have a 2D array and `df.drop()` takes only a 1D array or list-like object. Luckily you can use indexing or `flatten()` to sort it right out.

If your array were named, for example, `ind`:

```
df1=df.drop(ind.flatten(), axis=0)
```

or

```
df1=df.drop(ind[0], axis=0)
```

Either should work, but it's difficult to know without seeing sample data

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code but it gives me error. I've added example code with a data sample as well